# Using .each() to calculate fields within loop

Tags: jquery

I have table with inputs: price, quanitity, total before tax and total after tax. I would like to calculate price x quantity = total before tax and total before tax x vat = total after tax. I would like to calculate this using jQuery, but cannot figure it out!

```
jQuery(".acf-repeater .acf-row").each(function(element) {
  var row = $(element);
  var orderrow_quantity = row.find(".orderrow-quantity input").val();
  var orderrow_price_before_tax = row.find(".orderrow-price-before-vat input").val();
  var orderrow_total_before_tax = orderrow_quantity * orderrow_price_before_tax;
  var orderrow_total_after_tax = orderrow_total_before_tax * vat_percentage;
  row.find(".orderrow-total-before-vat input").val(orderrow_total_before_tax);
  row.find(".orderrow-total-after-vat input").val(orderrow_total_after_tax);
});
```

Comment: The problem is because the first argument in the `each()` handler function is the element index, not a reference to the element itself. To fix this either use `var row = $(this);`, or change the function definition to `.each(function(i, element) {`. Closing as a typographical issue in either case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either change the param or use the `$(this)` instead of `$(element)`

```
jQuery(".acf-repeater .acf-row").each(function(i, element) {
  var row = $(element);
  var orderrow_quantity = row.find(".orderrow-quantity input").val();
  ...
});
```

OR

```
jQuery(".acf-repeater .acf-row").each(function() {
  var row = $(this);
  var orderrow_quantity = row.find(".orderrow-quantity input").val();
  ...
});
```

Hope this will helps you.